# how "A loop" complete in a clock

Tags: vhdl

I try to find many code to reference.

But I can't find the solution for I need.

Can anyone help me find the question & solution?

Thank you very much.

The question is that i need this code can variable.

```
ero_check_t <= erosion_buf(0)(0)+erosion_buf(0)(1)+erosion_buf(0)(2)+
               erosion_buf(1)(0)+erosion_buf(1)(1)+erosion_buf(1)(2)+
               erosion_buf(2)(0)+erosion_buf(2)(1)+erosion_buf(2)(2);
```

like the up code(3*3) can variable to the down code(2*2).

```
ero_check_t <= erosion_buf(0)(0)+erosion_buf(0)(1)+
               erosion_buf(1)(0)+erosion_buf(1)(1);
```

how can I write? Can use loop to code?

```
process(rst)
begin
    if rst = '0' then
        ero_check   <= "0000000000";
        ero_check_t <= "0000000000";
    else
        for i in 0 to array_x loop
            for j in 0 to (array_y - 1) loop
                if i = array_x then
                    if j= 0 then
                        ero_check_t  <= ero_check;
                        ero_check    <= "0000000000";
                        exit;
                    end if;
                else
                    ero_check := ero_check + erosion_buf(i)(j);
                end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
    end if;
end process;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is YES. The longer answer is that you might want to check your code does exactly what you want (and there are some problems with it, too). If you want *combinational* logic that does this:

```
ero_check_t <= erosion_buf(0)(0)+erosion_buf(0)(1)+erosion_buf(0)(2) + ...
               erosion_buf(1)(0)+erosion_buf(1)(1)+erosion_buf(1)(2) + ...
               erosion_buf(2)(0)+erosion_buf(2)(1)+erosion_buf(2)(2) + ...
               ...
```

Then something like this would do the trick:

```
process(erosion_buf)              -- erosion_buf is the only input
  variable e :                    -- the same type as ero_check_t
begin
  e :=                            -- zero (I don't know what type ero_check_t is)
  for i in 0 to array_x-1 loop    -- assuming array_x is the LENGTH of the x dimension
    for j in 0 to array_y-1 loop  -- assuming array_y is the LENGTH of the y dimension
       e := e + erosion_buf(i)(j);                     
    end loop;
  end loop;
  ero_check_t <= e;               -- drive the output signal
end process;
```

`ero_chek` is a *variable*. This is initialised to zero and then the nested loops do all the additions. Finally, you drive the signal `ero_check_t` with the contents of the variable `ero_check`.

Comment: here is ero_check 's type:(ero_check_t  is same.)     
    signal ero_check   : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0):="0000000000";

           And ero_check_t  is used to output ,just want to accept the lastest data.

Comment: Well, ero_check_t is doing what you expect, then. If the type is `std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)`, then you are going to need some type conversion: you can't add `std_logic_vector` - there is no `+` operator defined. See [my company's webite](https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/numeric_std/).

Comment: Declare the types as unsigned (or signed if appropriate) and arrays of them, and the right operators will be defined.